# Flutter - Nested (Child) Navigation with Getx

Tags: flutter, nested, navigation, children, flutter-getx

I need to have this use case to be done.
I have a dashboard with a header and footer. Lets say, footer have bottom navigation bar, and the header have some banner with company details.
I need to to render Products, Favourites, Orders components inside the Dashboard.

So, basically, keeping same navigation bar, and the header banner, need only to render the middle body part.

Here is the snippet of my routing:

```
GetPage(
      name: '/dashboard', 
      page: () => Dashboard(), 
      middlewares: [
        AuthGuard(),
      ],
      children: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/products',
          page: () => Products(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/favorites',
          page: () => Favorites(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/orders',
          page: () => Orders(),
        ),
    ]),
```

Example Video:
[image]

PS: Gif and the code snippet was taken from internet. But the scenario is same as this.

PS: Old days I used auto_route and this use case was able to be done by placing AutoRouter() widget inside the component to render the child component inside it. But had a issue with using Get.toNamed() with auto_route. And unable to add bindings with auto_route. Please consider, I need to do it using GetX routing.